# translation invariance of the Laughlin wave function

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, topological-quantum-field-theory

This is a translation into math of the [following question](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/25073/translation-invariance-of-the-laughlin-wavefunction?show=25073#q25073), posted on PhysicsOverflow.

Let $H:=L^2(\mathbb C)$.
For every $N$, let $\psi_N\in\Lambda^N H\cong (L^2(\mathbb C^N))^{S_N}$ be the function
$$
\psi_N(z_1,\ldots,z_N):=c\cdot\prod_{i<j}(z_i-z_j)^3\prod_i e^{-|z_i|^2/4},
$$
normalized so as to have $\|\psi_N\|^2=1$.
 (Note that I could have replaced the $3$ above by any other odd integer — those are also called `[Laughlin wave functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laughlin_wavefunction)'.)

Let $D\subset \mathbb C$ be a unit disc, not necessarily centered at the origin. Let $H_{in}=L^2(D)$ and $H_{out}=L^2(\mathbb C\setminus D)$, so that $H=H_{in}\oplus H_{out}$.
We then have a decomposition
$$
\Lambda^N H=\bigoplus_{k=0}^N (\Lambda^kH_{in})\otimes (\Lambda^{N-k}H_{out})
$$
Write $\psi_{N,k}$ for the $k$-th summand of $\psi_N$ in the above direct sum decomposition.

> **Question 1:** For any given $k$, is the limit
>   $$
> \lim_{N\to \infty} \|\psi_{N,k}\|^2 
> $$
>   (assuming it exists) independent of $D$?

*Definition:* Given a unit vector $\zeta=\sum_i\xi_i\otimes \eta_i\in H\otimes K$ in the tensor product of two Hilbert spaces, the `[reduced density matrix](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/104511/what-is-the-reduced-density-matrix/104533#104533)' is the operator $[\zeta]_H:H\to H$ given by
$$[\zeta]_H(x):= \sum_i \langle x,\xi_i\rangle \|\eta_i\|^2  \xi_i.$$
Equivalently, $[\zeta]_H$ is the partial trace of the rank one projection onto the line spanned by $\zeta$.
(Sub-question: what's the correct math terminology and notation for $[\zeta]_H$?)

Let us from now on abbreviate $[-]_{H_{in}}$ by $[-]_{in}$.

> **Question 2** (which implies Question 1)**:** For any given $k$, is the limit
>   $$
> \lim_{N\to \infty} [\psi_{N,k}]_{in}
> $$
>   (assuming it exists) independent of $D$?

Here, to make sense of Question 2, we need to identify the Hilbert spaces $H_{in}=L^2(D_1)$ and $H_{in}=L^2(D_2)$ associated to any two discs $D_1,D_2\subset \mathbb C$. This is done by the `[magnetic translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_translation)' operator, which sends $f\in L^2(D_1)$ to $f_\tau\in L^2(D_2)$ defined by $$f_\tau(z):=e^{\mathrm{Im}(\bar \tau z)}f(z-\tau)$$ where $D_2=D_1+\tau$. (and I may be missing some minus sign or $2\pi$ in the exponent.)

Comment: the physics answer is that $|\psi|^2=\exp[-\beta H(z_1,z_2,\ldots z_N)]$ has the interpretation of a Gibbs distribution of $N$ classical particles in a disc with a parabolic confining potential, interacting with a logarithmic $-\ln|z_i-z_j|$ interaction, at inverse temperature $\beta=q$, where in your case $q=3$. So the question boils down to asking whether this classical statistical mechanical system is a liquid, hence translational invariant, or a crystal without translational invariance. The answer needs numerical calculations: the liquid exists for $q<70$, for larger $q$ it's a crystal.

Comment: the point I want to make is this: since for some exponents $q$ in $|z_i-z_j|^q$ this $\psi_N$ is translationally invariant and for other exponents $q$ it is not, I don't think you can expect a proof (without numerical calculations) that will tell you the system is translationally invariant for $q=3$.

Comment: The Laughlin wave function is certainly (and visibly) rotationally invariant, and I've never heard of rotationally invariant crystals... so I'm a bit confused by what you mean by "crystal". Could you maybe elaborate?

Comment: the "crystal" refers to the marginal distribution $N^{-1}\sum_{n}P(|z_n|)$, the probability to find a particle at distance $r=|z|$ from the origin of the potential well; in the "liquid" phase this distribution decays smoothly from the origin, and is constant on the scale $1/\sqrt N$ of the average interparticle separation. In the "crystal" phase this distribution has peaks on this scale: the first particle will prefer to set at the center of the well, and then the next particle will be at some fixed radial separation from it, and so on.

Comment: figure 3 of this reference http://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.2320v1.pdf shows the electron density in the liquid phase, so for $\nu=3$; the bulk density is uniform, but in the crystal phase, $\nu>70$, the oscillations persist in the bulk.

Comment: If I could chip in: the question being posed is more basic, and is concerned with whether the density of the Laughlin state is translationally invariant. It is not, on account of the Gaussian factor, and this leads to a circular Quantum Hall droplet even for low $q$.

Comment: This is no problem: a droplet centered at $z_0$ may be obtained by adding a factor $e^{z_iz_0/2}$ for each coordinate, which retains the desired properties of the Laughlin state but shifts the density.

Comment: Austen: I realize that the density of the Laughlin state is not translationally invariant in your above naive sense. That's why I took the effort to make the question mathematically precise (with reduced density matrices and all that technical stuff).

Comment: Isn't the quantity defined in question 1 just the probability to find k particles in D? Then the answer is evidently no, for the same naive reason. That is, if you put the disk where the density is small, the above probability is small.

Comment: Austen: Yes. It's the probability to find k particles in D. But you first fix the position of the disc, and then let $N\to \infty$. So you don't have the freedom to reposition your disc where the density is small.

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker : What about Laughlins wavefunction on the sphere ? In this case Laughlins wavefunction is SU(2) invariant.

Comment: On a sphere you'll want to specify the angular momentum $L$ of the wave function, which is rotational invariant for $L=0$, but not for $L\neq 0$. The ground state (for a given flux through the sphere) has $L=0$ and is rotational invariant.

Comment: I'm not very knowledgeable in all this. May I ask what is the formula of the Laughlin ground state on the sphere (for a given flux $L$ through the sphere)?